# Javascript replace with regex not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

I'm trying to validate a name with regex, the regex stops the user from entering 2 spaces or dots in a row.

This is my code:

```js
function test(input) {
  var regex = /^[A-Za-z]+\.{0,1}\s{0,1}$/;
  input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}
```

```html
<input id="txt_NomCandidato" onkeyup="test(this);" type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_Nom">
```

At the moment I want to enter a letter, I cant I don't know why, I hope you guys can help.

EDIT: Name only contains letters, not numbers.

Comment: FYI `{0,1}` is the same as `?`

Comment: Your regex matches what I assume you actually want to allow. Since you are then in turn using it to replace, it removes anything that matches it.

Comment: *... **the regex stops** the user from entering 2 spaces or dots in a row.* it's not clear if you are trying to avoid two spaces or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should work for you: `/[^a-zA-Z. ]|\.(?=\.)|\s(?=\s)/g`

- `[^a-zA-Z. ]+` Limits all allowed characters to a-z, A-Z, dots, or spaces
- `\.(?=\.)` Limits it to only allow one dot in a row
- `\s(?=\s)` Limits it to only one space in a row

Each of these are separated by | (the or condition)

```js
function test(input) {
  var regex = /[^a-zA-Z. ]|\.(?=\.)|\s(?=\s)/g;
  input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}
```

```html
<input id="txt_NomCandidato" onkeyup="test(this);" type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_Nom">
```

Answer (score 2):

With this solution it deletes only the second space or second dot and the first ones will still remain:

```js
function test(input){
  var regex=/\.(?=\.)|\s(?=\s)/;
  input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}
```

```html
<input id="txt_NomCandidato" onkeyup="test(this);" type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_Nom">
```

Comment: The issue of your regex is that i can enter numbers and special characters

Comment: @YosetGA so you want your own regex validation plus the thing with double dots and spaces?

Answer (score 1):

This regex will not allow them to enter two periods or two spaces, when they enter the second of either it will clear.

```js
function test(input){
  var regex=/\.{2}| {2}/;
  input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "").replace(/\d+|/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(/[^\w]/, '');
}
```

```html
<input id="txt_NomCandidato" onkeyup="test(this);" type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_Nom">
```

Comment: This wouldn't validate a name simultaneously.

Comment: I didn't see that was part of it edited to only allow letters as well as stop dots and spaces.

Comment: Ok stops those now as well.

Comment: You first remove all digits then exclude them from removing. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex seems correct (it matches any string with no more than 1 space or 1 dot together), but your the logic in your function seems wrong.

What it's doing: anytime the value changes, take the value and replace anything that matches that regex with an empty string, so any time you write a character its replaced (because it matches the regex).

I would go with one of this options:

a) show a message if the value doesn't match the regex

b) change the regex to /.{2}| {2}/ and only replace the two dots or the two spaces, as Scath says in another answer

c) maybe just using the input pattern attribute with your original regex is enough: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_pattern.asp

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

That is because you match `[A-Za-z]+` which will match one or more characters and everything after that is optional.

Your regex would match.

- `[A-Za-z]+` Match one or more characters
- `\.{0,1}` Match optional dot (0 or 1 times)
- `\s{0,1}` match optional whitespace character (0 or 1 times)

Which will match `a` and then you will do the replace.

To make something optional you could also use a [question mark](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`

To only allow characters, a single whitespace or a single dot you could replace all that does not match those criteria:

[`([. ])(?=\1)|[^a-zA-Z. ]`](https://regex101.com/r/BBVoJi/1)

```js
function test(input) {
  var regex = /([. ])(?=\1)|[^a-zA-Z. ]/;
  input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}
```

```html
<form id="" name="">
  <input id="txt_NomCandidato" onkeyup="test(this);" type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_Nom">
</form>
```

To match a dot followed by a dot or a white space followed by a white space you could capture a dot or a white space in a group and it will match if it is followed by what is captured in the group using a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

[`([. ])(?=\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/pARs0O/1/)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of slice

input.value.slice(-2) will return last two entered characters and if it is ".." or "  "(double spaces) replace it with ''

```js
function test(input){
  if(input.value.slice(-2)=='..' || input.value.slice(-2)=='  '){
         input.value = input.value.replace(input.value.slice(-2), "");
     }
}
```

```html
<input id="txt_NomCandidato" onkeyup="test(this);" type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_Nom">
```

code sample -  https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VXNOej

Your regex clears any characters starts with [A-Z] or [a-z] due to expression **^[A-Za-z]**